# Mysql Deadlock in Stored Procedure,composite unique key

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, deadlock, unique-index

I have a table with composite unique key(uniqueness on combination of 3 columns.)
Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `userreview` (
 `cid` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `conid` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `userid` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `flag` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `updatedat` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON 
  UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_userreview_cid_conid_userid` (`cid`,`conid`,`userid`)
 ) ;
```

Below is stored procedure .

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `testdeadlock`(IN pconid   BIGINT(12), IN pcid 
  BIGINT(12), IN puserid BIGINT(12),IN pflag INT(1))
  BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
  BEGIN
   ROLLBACK;
   RESIGNAL;
 END;

START TRANSACTION;  
IF pflag = 1 THEN

 INSERT ignore into userreview(cid,conid,userid,flag)
            VALUES(pcid,pconid,puserid,1)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = 1;
         /*update operation in table 1*/
 ELSEIF pflag = 0 THEN

   INSERT ignore into userreview(cid,conid,userid)
            VALUES(pcid,pconid,puserid)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = 0;
       /*update operation in table 2*/
    ELSEIF pflag = 2 THEN

    INSERT ignore into userreview(cid,conid,userid)
            VALUES(pcid,pconid,puserid)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = 2;
       /*update operation in table 3*/
 end if;
COMMIT;
end;
```

When this procedure is executing from client side(using node.js),sometime it occurs deadlock when concurrent transactions are going to execute on same rows.Though there is unique index still facing deadlock problem.
Is there any suggestion to avoid deadlock?

Deadlock result:-

```
                LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
            ------------------------
            2018-07-06 16:55:51 0x2b0b08e99700
            *** (1) TRANSACTION:
            TRANSACTION 102648166, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
            mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
            LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
            MySQL thread id 108948, OS thread handle 47323865503488, query id 242017676 10.0.3.130 numbertankroot update
            INSERT ignore into userreview(cid,conid,userid,flag)
                    VALUES( NAME_CONST('pcid',8157), NAME_CONST('pconid',3158), NAME_CONST('puserid',85217))
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = 0
            *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
            RECORD LOCKS space id 735 page no 17308 n bits 256 index idx_userreview_cid_conid_userid of table `userreview` trx id 102648166 lock_mode X waiting
            Record lock, heap no 183 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 15; compact format; info bits 0
             0: len 8; hex 0000000000001fdd; asc         ;;
             1: len 8; hex 000000000005af9f; asc         ;;
             2: len 8; hex 00000000000bd0b7; asc         ;;
             3: len 6; hex 0000061e4965; asc     Ie;;
             4: len 7; hex 2800000eb42873; asc (    (s;;
             5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
             6: len 1; hex 84; asc  ;;
             7: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
             8: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
             9: len 8; hex 0000000000001fdd; asc         ;;
             10: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
             11: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
             12: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
             13: len 6; hex 5b3f9f170000; asc [?    ;;
             14: len 6; hex 5b3f9f17213e; asc [?  !>;;

            *** (2) TRANSACTION:
            TRANSACTION 102648170, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
            mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
            4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s)
            MySQL thread id 108960, OS thread handle 47326394160896, query id 242017689 10.0.3.130 numbertankroot update
            INSERT ignore into userreview(cid,conid,userid,flag)
                    VALUES( NAME_CONST('pcid',8157), NAME_CONST('pconid',3158), NAME_CONST('puserid',85217))
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = 1
            *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
            RECORD LOCKS space id 735 page no 17308 n bits 256 index `idx_userreview_cid_conid_userid` of table `userreview` trx id 102648170 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
            Record lock, heap no 183 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 15; compact format; info bits 0
             0: len 8; hex 0000000000001fdd; asc         ;;
             1: len 8; hex 000000000005af9f; asc         ;;
             2: len 8; hex 00000000000bd0b7; asc         ;;
             3: len 6; hex 0000061e4965; asc     Ie;;
             4: len 7; hex 2800000eb42873; asc (    (s;;
             5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
             6: len 1; hex 84; asc  ;;
             7: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
             8: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
             9: len 8; hex 0000000000001fdd; asc         ;;
             10: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
             11: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
             12: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
             13: len 6; hex 5b3f9f170000; asc [?    ;;
             14: len 6; hex 5b3f9f17213e; asc [?  !>;;

            *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
            RECORD LOCKS space id 735 page no 17308 n bits 256 index `idx_userreview_cid_conid_userid` of table  `userreview` trx id 102648170 lock_mode X waiting
            Record lock, heap no 183 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 15; compact format; info bits 0
             0: len 8; hex 0000000000001fdd; asc         ;;
             1: len 8; hex 000000000005af9f; asc         ;;
             2: len 8; hex 00000000000bd0b7; asc         ;;
             3: len 6; hex 0000061e4965; asc     Ie;;
             4: len 7; hex 2800000eb42873; asc (    (s;;
             5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
             6: len 1; hex 84; asc  ;;
             7: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
             8: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
             9: len 8; hex 0000000000001fdd; asc         ;;
             10: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
             11: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
             12: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
             13: len 6; hex 5b3f9f170000; asc [?    ;;
             14: len 6; hex 5b3f9f17213e; asc [?  !>;;

            *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

- You can not combine `INSERT IGNORE` and `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. This doesn't make sense.
- Your whole `IF` block can be reduced to one statement:

  ```
  INSERT into userreview(cid,conid,userid,flag)
      VALUES(pcid,pconid,puserid,1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = pflag;
  ```
- Since you can reduce the whole procedure to one statement, actually the whole procedure is superfluous
- Are you really, really sure, that the deadlocks are colliding `INSERT` statements? I have my doubts. Have you examined the deadlock section of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`? If yes, post the result.
- Regarding my doubts that the problem are actually only the insert statements, there is nothing in the manual, that describes how this should be possible. The only way for deadlocks to occur with insert statements would be that there are gap locks, which would only occur with a unique index when not all columns of the combined index are used in the search condition. Which is not the case here. As a final note, here's the manual page for [How to Minimize and Handle Deadlocks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html). Hope it helps...

EDIT after question update:

I can only quote one of the tipps given in the link I already provided:

> Keep transactions small and short in duration to make them less prone to collision.

It's not a problem with the insert statements in particular. The transaction as a whole is taking too long.

Comment: Thank You for your explanation.I updated my question why i am using if elseif statement.Also i am posing deadlock result.

Comment: @5a01d01P Updated my answer as well.